# How to do substitution using "Sed" from external files

Tags: linux

So my current_file looks like this

```
(<PREFIX><SUFFIX>|<STANDALONESUFFIX>) (<PREFIX><SUFFIX>|<STANDALONESUFFIX>)(<PREFIX><SUFFIX>|<STANDALONESUFFIX>)?
```

I have an external file called "prefixfile" contains:

```
b
p
m
f
d
```

and a file called "Suffixfile" contains:

```
u
ai
an
ao
```

and a file called 'standalone_suffixfile' containing:

```
ai
ei
ao
ou
an
ang
en
```

My task is to replace the `<PREFIX>` in my current_file with the content of prefix file mentioned above, then `<SUFFIX>` with the content of suffix file and `<STANDALONESUFFIX>` with the content of standalone_suffix file.

I want to get something like

```
bu mai dao
```

which is a Mandarin Name generated from combining prefix suffix or just from standalone suffix it can be other than that as long as the name comes from that 3 files I mentioned above.

I tried
`sed -e '/<PREFIX>/r prefixfile' -e '/<PREFIX>/d' current_file`

but it doesn't seem to do it correctly, can anyone show me how to do it

Comment: If you paste in your data as line-by-line, and it displays as one line, you should at least include a note that the formatting is not right. In the future, use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. I would look at solving this problem with `awk`. It may be possible with `sed`, but only for those that enjoy solving the Towers-of-Hanoi puzzle with the barest of tools. Good luck.

Comment: The `()` and `<>` chars often have meta-meanings in shell, sed and awk. You can simplify your problem significantly by using other chars, maybe `PR, SF, SS` . Good luck.